# Creating Gradients

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox, responsive

I have a .hero image that I would like to take up 100% of the viewport while remaining responsive on smaller devices. However, the picture actually cuts off when it's in mobile view. To make matters worse, for whatever reason, my text isn't centered in the middle of the .hero image. I just needed some help with these two things. I've been working on it for an hour to no avail. 
Thanks

```css
  * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  display: block;
  margin-top: -10px: width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: black;
  height: 30%;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.hero {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(76, 76, 76, 1);
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/7094/wood-coffee-laptop-hero-7094.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940);
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

nav {
  display: block;
}

nav li {
  font-weight: 700;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

li {
  border-top: grey solid 1px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 45px;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  border-top: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

li:nth-child(4) {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.side1 {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.main-content {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.side2 {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 726px) {
  @media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .header {
      display:flex;
    }
    header {
      -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
      -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
      box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
      width: 100%;
      align-items: center;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: white;
      border-color: black;
      height: 30%;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    nav {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }
    li:nth-child(1) {
      border-top: grey solid 1px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-around;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .hero {
      margin-bottom: 3%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .main-content {
      border-left: lightgrey 1px solid;
      border-right: lightgrey 1px solid;
      width: 33.3%;
    }
    .side1 {
      width: 30%;
    }
    .side2 {
      width: 30%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300i" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <li><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Heading1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Heading2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Heading3</a></li>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="hero">
    <div class="text">
      <h1>Anna Gibson</h1>
      <h2>Web Dev. Writer. Thinker</h2>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="side1">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
      <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="main-content">
      <h2>Main-content</h2>
      <p>
        "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human
        happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves
        or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical
        exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="side2">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
      <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can't tell which part is the relevant part of the code and where are the gradients you are referring to. Can you edit your question and only include the important parts?

Comment: Never mind, I appreciate it but I actually managed to fix the problem on my own.

Comment: In other words, she has abandoned the question and won't give the solution that others may learn from.

Comment: You’re right. I’ll provide the answer when I get home. Didn’t consider that.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what u want?

i have centered the text vertically and horizontally.

As for the image which is landscape mode image , u r using full height of screen which is in landscape mode.

So on mobile screen which is portrait mode , the image will try take full height of the screen, leading to clipping of the image

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  display: block;
  margin-top: -10px: width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: black;
  height: 30%;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.hero {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(76, 76, 76, 1);
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/7094/wood-coffee-laptop-hero-7094.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940);
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

nav {
  display: block;
}

nav li {
  font-weight: 700;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

li {
  border-top: grey solid 1px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 45px;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  border-top: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

li:nth-child(4) {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.side1 {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.main-content {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.side2 {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 726px) {
  @media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .header {
      display:flex;
    }
    header {
      -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
      -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
      box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
      width: 100%;
      align-items: center;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: white;
      border-color: black;
      height: 30%;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    nav {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }
    li:nth-child(1) {
      border-top: grey solid 1px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-around;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .hero {
      margin-bottom: 3%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .main-content {
      border-left: lightgrey 1px solid;
      border-right: lightgrey 1px solid;
      width: 33.3%;
    }
    .side1 {
      width: 30%;
    }
    .side2 {
      width: 30%;
    }
  }
}

.text {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300i" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <li><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Heading1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Heading2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Heading3</a></li>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="hero">
    <div class="text">
      <h1>Anna Gibson</h1>
      <h2>Web Dev. Writer. Thinker</h2>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="side1">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
      <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="main-content">
      <h2>Main-content</h2>
      <p>
        "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human
        happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves
        or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical
        exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="side2">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
      <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I did. (I'll only post what's relevant to the question at hand.)

This is the HTML...

```
 <div class="hero">
    <div class="text">
      <h1>Anna Gibson</h1>
      <h2>Web Dev. Writer. Thinker.</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the CSS...

```
hero {
   height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  filter:brightness(20%);
background:
 url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/7094/wood-coffee-laptop-hero-7094.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940);
    position:relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index:-1;
}

.text {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  align-self: : center;
  padding-top: 200px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Oswald, serif;
}
```

In order to center the text I simply put 'align-self' center and provided 20 pixels of padding to the top of the container and a width of 100%, so that it'll constantly stay in the center of the .hero container.